# Undefined method '' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby

Just trying to make a simple shopping cart for an application selling bikes using ruby. This error has me bogged down so any help would be very appreciated!

The error comes up when I want to add something to the cart. Its something to do with my controller of the lineitems or my cart model.

For my line items:

```
@lineitem = @cart.add_bike(bike.id)
```

For my model:

```
def add_bike(bike_id)
  current_item = lineitems.find_by_bike_id(bike_id)
  if current_item
    current_item.quantity +=1
  else
    current_item = lineitems.new(bike_id: bike_id)
    current_item.quantity = 1
  end
  current_item          #this is returning the current_item object  
end
```

My error in full is `` undefined method `add_bike' for nil:NilClass ``

```
def current_cart
  @cart = Cart.find(session[:cart_id])
  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
    @cart = Cart.create
    session[:cart_id] = @cart.id
  end
end
```

Comment: is the model the cart model?  Unless I am missing something `add_bike` <> `add_product` ?

Comment: The code seems incomplete.  If not, then `@cart` is not initialized.

Comment: Where's the rest of the code when you call `add_bike` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@cart` isn't initialized in your controller, and is equal to `nil`.

Your `@cart` isn't a cart, and `add_bike` isn't defined for something that isn't a cart.

You should show us what happens before `@cart.add_bike(bike.id)`

Update :

- It looks like you don't call `current_cart` before using `@cart.add_bike(bike.id)`
- Your `current_cart` defines `@cart` but returns `@cart.id` when a new `@cart` is created.

Comment: I didn't have before_action :current_cart, only: [:create]. That seems to be the problem

Comment: You shouldn't use answers to ask for clarification, that's what comments are for.

Comment: Let's say it was a rhetorical question. Given his `current_cart` method and the error he got, it was clear that `current_cart` wasn't called. Still, I updated my answer. Thanks for the comment

Comment: Thanks Eric, really helped. Don't mind that Stefan lad

Comment: That "Stefan lad" also happens to be a very valuable source of Ruby info. ;)

Comment: Sorry if I sounded rude.